# Real-Time Subscriptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

Good afternoon,
I'm using version 5.4.1 of the Facebook C# SDK. I should note that I am using the source code directly rather than the DLLs (in case this makes any difference).

So the fact that filter attributes are setup is awesome (thank you dev team :).

My issue is occurring during the initial request (before I get to using verifying the GET response from Facebook)

Here is my initial request:

```
dynamic result = fb.Post(
                string.Format("/{0}/subscriptions", 
                     FacebookApplication.Current.AppId),
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {"object", "user"},
                        {"fields", "friends"},
                        {
                            "callback_url",
                            "http://localhost:16917/subscription/verify"
                            },
                        {
                            "verify_token",
                            "77FB802F-1147-48F0-BB0F-E4E9BC1FBCFC"
                            }
                    });
```

I'm finding that an exception is internally being thrown and via Fiddler I'm seeing that the request is never going out. The exception is:

```
$exception  {"(OAuthException) (#15) This method must be called with an app access_token."} System.Exception {Facebook.FacebookOAuthException}
```

I initially thought this may be related to Facebook.FacebookClient's PrepareRequest method:

```
if (httpMethod == HttpMethod.Get)
{
    // for GET, all parameters goes as querystrings
    input = null;
    queryString.Append(FacebookUtils.ToJsonQueryString(parameters));
}
else
{
    if (parameters.ContainsKey("access_token"))
    {
        queryString.AppendFormat("access_token={0}", parameters["access_token"]);
        parameters.Remove("access_token");
    }
}
```

but commenting out the line `parameters.Remove("access_token");` made no difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I should note that I'm initially calling this from the account controller AFTER the user has authorized my application

Comment: How many FB cookies do you have? It could possibly be related an issue I was getting yesterday with the Facebook C# SDK... it was fixed by setting `cookie: 'yourbasedomain'` instead of `cookie: true` in the facebook javascript init.

Comment: not sure if it's that but I will check if there is a related parameter in C# - I am using the SDK without javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What access_token are you using?

Are you using a User's access token, or an App access token?

If you are using an User's access token take a look here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#app-login on how to get an App access token.

Comment: fb.Post uses the Facebook client - the example Post I'm using is using the example given in the notes for the Facebook.Web.FacebookSubscriptionsHttpHandler as a guideline

Comment: When newing up your FacebookClient are you using the constructor that accepts your app id and app secret?  This will make it create an App access token for you to make that call with.

Comment: You can see the code where the fb client is created in the FacebookCallback method here: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f77714d15792#Samples%2fCS-AspNetMvc3-WithoutJsSdk%2fControllers%2fAccountController.cs

Comment: As I'm testing this functionality, I'm simply making the call from there, at the end of the method, using that instance of the FacebookClient

Comment: That looks like it is going to be using a User access token.  Try newing the FacebookClient with FacebookApplication.Current instead of accessToken

Comment: yeah that was it thanks :) I accidentally pointed you in the wrong direction - I was using ProcessSuccessfulFacebookCallback, but editing the request to use FacebookApplication.Current resulted in "{\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#2200) callback verification failed: \",\"type\":\"OAuthException\"}}" which is expected as I still need to map the service to the outside world. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the app access_token.

You can easily create an app access_token using the following constructor.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("appid", "appsecret");
dynamic result = fb.Post( .... );
```